# when use Curl get error not found curl in directory

Tags: php, curl, composer-php

I get an error when sending curl in php

```
Undetected error: "Curl \ Curl" class not found in / usr / share / nginx / html / myproject
```

composer installed and dumpautoload but the error was not fixed.

my code

```
$curl = new Curl\Curl();
    $curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    $curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $curl_method = strtolower($method);
    $curl->$curl_method($this->base_url . $url . '?' . http_build_query($data));
```

composer.json

```
"require": {
    "longman/telegram-bot": "^0.74.0",
    "intervention/image": "^2.6",
    "kwn/number-to-words": "^2.0",
    "gregwar/captcha": "^1.1",
    "kavenegar/php": "^1.2",
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "ext-mysqli": "*",
    "curl/curl": "^2.3",
    "ext-gd": "*",
    "ext-redis": "^5.3",
    "ext-zlib": "*",
    "ext-openssl": "*",
    "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.18",
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.5",
    "icamys/php-sitemap-generator": "^4.3",
    "php-curl-class/php-curl-class": "^9.6"
},
```

Comment: are you using [curl\curl package](https://packagist.org/packages/curl/curl)? that `curl` and php's built in [`curl`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) are two different stuff - though the former used the later. it would be helpful if you could share a bit of the offending code and the `composer.json` file.

Comment: sure. edit the question now

Comment: If that is the **whole** code, you are missing the inclusion of the autoloader

Comment: hi, have you loaded the `autoload.php`? something like `require 'vendor/autoload.php'` on top most of your code.

Comment: no, I don't required any file @BagusTesa

Comment: hi @NicoHaase yes not found autoloader  in composer.json

Comment: "not found autoloader in composer.json" - what does that mean? Your own code needs to include the autoloader, like any basic Composer tutorial tells you. Otherwise, it's obvious that PHP cannot find the class you are using

Comment: @NicoHaase when add require 'vendor/autoload.php' receive  error failed to load data response
when api test with postman its trust

Comment: What do you mean by "its trust"? Also, if that is a **different** error message, you should open a different question for this. Finally, add **all** clarification to your question by editing it